# Persistent child view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

How would I be able to have a child view controller be persistent in an iOS app? When you switch from one view controller to another, the child view controller won't update, just stay in place. A good example is the sound manager / audio player view in the Spotify app.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they move it across views and its not automatically done

Comment: I was trying to do this recently. Found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17759156/2410991

Comment: @JoshCaswell.. Thanx for letting me know. Still learning

Comment: @hw731 Damn! that what I was looking for. many thanks for the link! +1