# Make a UIVIew which appears on all .NIb files in xcode project

Tags: ios, uiview

I have a UIVIEW I want to make its appear on all controller like say I have 5 controllers,
1 , 2 ,3 ,4 , 5

I have a UIVIEW on controller1 at the bottom which contains 5 buttons I want that view to appear on all controllers, I have searched about it but didn't found any reasonable solution, Any here please help me out.I don't want to make navigationbar because I cannot add custom buttons on navigationbar.

Or is there any technique by which we can make a custom navigationbar? which appear at bottom, I already have a UINavigationbar at top

Comment: There is UITabBarController where you will have tab for respective view controllers OR you can create custom view that you can called in all of five controller.

Comment: You may have already seen this, but it helped me with a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17759156/2410991

Answer (score 1):

You can put your UIView with the 5 buttons in a separate nib (Im calling it BottomNavigation in my example) and then add it to each controllers view like this:

```
UIView* containerView = [UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGMakeRect(0, 440, 320, 40)]; //Adjust rect to your needs
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BottomNavigation" owner:containerView options:nil];
[self.view addSubView:containerView];
```

And if you want to set the target-action for the buttons in the containerView you could always iterate through them like this (before you add them as subview to your self.view):

```
for (UIView *view in containerView.subviews)
    {
        if ([view isMemberOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            //Here you should check the tag or equivalent to make sure your setting the target-action for the right UIButton
            [view addTarget:target action:@selector(MyMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Quiet good, But how I will access the action events of button in different controllers?, In all controllers all my action event will be same.

Comment: See my edit! This you have to do for all the controller if you want to have different targets and actions for these buttons