# How to change view with UITabBar (without using UITabBarController or addSubview)?

Tags: ios, view, switch-statement, uitabbar

I've tried a lot to get this done.I don't want want to use addsubview or uitabbarcontroller. I want to switch the view when I tap on different tabs and tabbar should stay there. Thanks a lot in advance.I m a newbie.I want to use uitabbar not uitabbarcontroller.

Comment: what do you want to happen when tapping ?

Comment: when i tap it should move on to a different view with the existing tabbar. And I should be able to perform any other to use buttons on the other view. In short I should be able to do everything that i can perform in a normalview controller. Just that the tabbar should stay there.

Comment: you are contradicting.  I don't want want to use addsubview or uitabbarcontroller, (i.e page shouldn't navigate) is what you have told before

Comment: ok i accept that mistake. Page should navigate but the tabbar should stay there.

Comment: That tab bar remains present with a UITabBarController too. Are you talking about the selected tab icon not changing?

Comment: I know it can be done with uitabbarcontroller. But I don't want to use it. And what I am saying is I m not able to keep the tabbar as it is when I am navigating with the tap on the tabbar. the whole tabbar goes invisible when I navigate. I don't want to loose that tabbar while I am navigating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach would be to wrap the view controllers you are inserting in `UITabBarController` in a `UINavigationController` then you can simply push your new view to that `UINavigationController` and the tab bar would be always visible!

For more details refer [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/CombiningViewControllers.html)

**Edit:**
If you don't want to use `UITabBarController` then you need to do 2 things:

1. Add the tab bar View to `UIWindow` that way it would be always visible.
2. Scale/adjust the views in your view controllers to leave space for the tab bar

Comment: I don't want to use UITabBarController

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I've already added TabBar in window but when I tap on the other tab to navigate at that time I switch to the different view "but" tabBar gets invisible.

Comment: you might be doing something wrong, Compare your implementation with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758420/making-a-button-persistent-across-all-view-controllers

Comment: I am not using StoryBoard.