# Web View at the bottom of each UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, webview

I am creating an iOS version of my app. I need a ad banner at the bottom of the app. The banner is just a web view which is showing content from our Server.

In Android app we have created the WebView in activity and shown the pages using fragments. We need the same feature in iOS too, but I am not able to find a proper tool to do it.

I just need a WebView Banner at the bottom of all the ViewControllers. Is there any way to create one WebView Object and add to every ViewController or do I need to create separate WebView for all the UIViewControllers?

Comment: How about create a base ViewController then every viewController with webView is subClass of this base ViewController?

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758420/making-a-button-persistent-across-all-view-controllers change the uibutton to your uiwebview

Comment: @tnylee Thanks for the link. This worked for me and were easier to do then using other methods. I have posted an answer mentioning how I did it in my project.

Comment: you are welcome :D @noob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion from tnylee, the ContainerView method worked for me.

I basically created a new UIViewController, added ContainerView at top taking all the space and added UIWebView in bottom. After adding few usual Constraints, I removed the segue to the Main View Controller (Since I had an extra Loading Screen in start.) and moved it to the new ContainerViewController.

Now I just need to add an embed segue from the ContainerView (Not from ViewController) to the Main View Controller.

Here's how this looks in storyboard -

[image: Storyboard for Container]

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options for that;

### Number-1

You can create just one `UIWebViewController` and shown it on any other objects and windows even keyboard. All you need is that you have to add your `UIWebviewController` object to subview of last object of your window like that;

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject] addSubview:yourWebViewController];
```

### Number-2

Use Apple's iAd program. It'll handle that for you.
https://developer.apple.com/iad/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't work for me. The primary reason was too much trouble in creating WebView dynamically.