# Display buttons above UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I am trying to display a button above my UIPageViewControllers views. 
I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758420/making-a-button-persistent-across-all-view-controllers) which suggests a solution that I already seem to be implementing.

This is my main storyboard:

[image: Sotryboard]

And this is my initial ViewController Scene

[image: ViewController Scene]

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.
Is it possible that this doesnt work because the Views in question are part of UIPageViewController?

If so how would i create buttons that appear above the UIPageViewController's views?

I would also like the buttons not to appear above other views that are not part of my UIPageViewController. So if I navigate from my UIPageViewController to another view controller I would like the buttons to disappear.

Is there an elegant solution for this case?